# Converting .json files to .ts files using tsc

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, typescript, tsc

My express folder in the react project (made with create-react-app) has `.ts` files and `.json` files. I want to convert `.ts` files to `.js` files internally using the tsc tool. As I want to build my express folder I need to convert all the files in the express folder to `.js` files. Now, I can convert the `.ts` files to `.js` files and store it into a different folder using the command `tsc --outDir dist src/**/*` . But this command throws an error on files which are not .ts. How can I convert all the files (including the ones which are not .ts, specifically .json files) using an internal tool/package such as tsc?

Stuck on this issue for quite sometime. Any help or directions would be helpful.

Comment: Do you use `--resolveJsonModule`? https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#new---resolvejsonmodule

Comment: Also, you can use gulp to automatically compile the files for you. https://gulpjs.com/

Comment: Yes, I do have `--resolveJsonModule` in my typescript.json file and it is set to True. The error it throws is that tsc can only convert files which are .ts, .tsx . Hence, I either have to convert .json files to a typescript files first and then use tsc on that folder or at least ignore those .json files while converting all the other typescript files to javascript files. Is there a way to ignore the .json files while using tsc.? @101arrowz

Answer (score 0):

you can insert 'include:[yourfiledir/**/*.js]' into 'tsconfig.json'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).